# Blink upon incoming call android

Tags: android, service, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener, window-managers

I am developing an android app, where I want make the home screen blink upon incoming call. I tried calling the below startblinking() method within a activity and the screen blinks fine.

But,
when I try to call the same method within the Ring state of a phonelistener(inside a Service class), I get the following error, since the service class doesnt have a window.

```
 The method getWindow() is undefined for the type PhoneListener
```

.

```
 private void startblinking()
{
     Log.e("inside","blink MEthod");

    timerforblinking.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {

                public void run() 
                {

                    time = (float) (time + 0.5);

                    if(time == 0.5 || time == 1.5 || time == 2.5 || time == 3.5 || time == 4.5 || time == 5.5)
                    {
                        Log.e("time","OFF  - time = "+time);

                        layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float) 30 / 255;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
                    }

                    if(time == 1.0 || time == 2.0 ||time == 3.0 ||time == 4.0 ||time == 5.0 )
                    {
                        Log.e("time","ON - time = "+time);

                        layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float)255 / 255;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
                    }

                    if(time >= 6.0)
                    {
                        layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float)255 / 255;
                        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);

                        timerforblinking.purge();
                        timerforblinking.cancel();
                    }
                }


            });
        }

    }, 0, 500);
```

Is there a possible workaround to achieve the screen blinking upon incoming calls.

Please help.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hand the Activity reference, which should blink, to the Service and call activity.getWindow(). You can use the Binder for this.

Have a field in your Service:

```
private Activity activity;
```

And a method in your Binder to update the field:

```
public void setActivity(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Call this when you are bound to the Service. Take care of this field at Activity switches or you will have a dead reference.